# Checking userform entries for duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a user form in VBA and I am checking the user inputs in the userform for duplicates in my database. I can get the userform to check for duplicates up to 4 criterions as shown below but once I include the check with the combobox MealPlan then it cannot see any duplicates anymore.

Here is my code below:

```
    Dim SprdSheet As Worksheet

    Set SprdSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LNR Rates")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SprdSheet.Range("D:D"), Me.Inncode_B.Value) > 0 And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SprdSheet.Range("F:F"), Me.CompanyName_B.Value) > 0 And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SprdSheet.Range("G:G"), Me.DNumber_B.Value) > 0 And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SprdSheet.Range("H:H"), Me.Rate_B.Value) > 0 And _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SprdSheet.Range("I:I"), Me.MealPlan_CB.Value) > 0 then 
        MsgBox "This is a duplicate"
        Exit Sub

    End If
```

For example the below code produces 450 error

```
        If Application.CountIfs(.Range("D:D"), Me.Inncode_B.Value, _
                                .Range("F:F"), Me.CompanyName_B.Value, _
                                .Range("G:G"), Me.DNumber_B.Value, _
                                .Range("H:H"), Me.Rate_B.Value, _
                                .Range("I:I"), Me.MealPlan_CB.Value, _
                                .Range("J:J"), Me.Parking_CB.Value, _
                                .Range("K:K"), Me.WIFI_CB.Value, _
                                .Range("L:L"), Me.LRANLRA_CB.Value, _
                                .Range("M:M"), Me.Comm_CB.Value, _
                                .Range("N:N"), Me.Cxl_CB.Value, _
                                .Range("O:O"), Me.OtherTC_B.Value, _
                                .Range("Q:Q"), Me.Live_B.Value, _
                                .Range("R:R"), Me.SRP_B.Value, _
                                .Range("S:S"), Me.SRPGroup_B.Value, _
                                .Range("T:T"), Me.Production_B.Value, _
                                .Range("U:U"), Me.LNRContact_B.Value) > 0 Then

                        MsgBox "This is a duplicate"

                        Exit Sub
```

But the code below here produces no error

```
    With SprdSheet
        If Application.CountIfs(.Range("D:D"), Me.Inncode_B.Value, _
                                .Range("F:F"), Me.CompanyName_B.Value, _
                                .Range("G:G"), Me.DNumber_B.Value, _
                                .Range("H:H"), Me.Rate_B.Value, _
                                .Range("I:I"), Me.MealPlan_CB.Value, _
                                .Range("J:J"), Me.Parking_CB.Value, _
                                .Range("K:K"), Me.WIFI_CB.Value, _
                                .Range("L:L"), Me.LRANLRA_CB.Value, _
                                .Range("M:M"), Me.Comm_CB.Value, _
                                .Range("N:N"), Me.Cxl_CB.Value, _
                                .Range("O:O"), Me.OtherTC_B.Value, _
                                .Range("R:R"), Me.SRP_B.Value, _
                                .Range("S:S"), Me.SRPGroup_B.Value, _
                                .Range("T:T"), Me.Production_B.Value, _
                                .Range("U:U"), Me.LNRContact_B.Value) > 0 Then

                        MsgBox "This is a duplicate"

                        Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: Your code only checks if a value in *any row* meets any *one* of those criteria - did you want to check for all those *in the same row* ?  You might need to use `Countifs()`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Tim. The code you provided seems to work when there are 15 or less arguments, but annoyingly mine has 16 arguments which I'm checking against in the database ie Inncode, company name, Dnumber...etc 16 of them. I keep getting the error Run-time error '450' Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. Is there a limit to the number of countifs?

Comment: According to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842 you can use up to 127 range/criteria pairs.  Is it just the Q:Q which gives the error?

Comment: @TimWilliams Perhaps worth pointing out per [WorksheetFunction.Countifs method documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countifs), it accepts up to 30 args, unlike the worksheet function's 127 - Also the syntax seems different between the two - My understanding of the WorksheetFunction.Countifs is that odd and even Args are paired (so *Arg1* represents *criteria_range1* and *Arg2* represents *criteria1*, etc).

Comment: Hi Tim, it doesn't matter which criterion I remove it works, but once I have 16 it gives me the 450 error. I'm a bit baffled if I'm honest. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @SamuelEverson - definitely worth pointing that out, and I would have done so it I'd  known there was difference in implementation between the two versions, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @TimWilliams I haven't done any specific research but I've noticed lately a lot of questions are revolving `WorksheetFunctions` methods and when looking into them it seems they all have a max of 30 Args.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only checks if all of those criteria are found on the sheet, but they could all be in different rows.

You might need to use `Countifs()`

```
Dim wsData As Worksheet

Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LNR Rates")

With wsData
    If Application.CountIfs(.Range("D:D"), Me.Inncode_B.Value, _
                            .Range("F:F"), Me.CompanyName_B.Value, _
                            .Range("G:G"), Me.DNumber_B.Value, _
                            .Range("H:H"), Me.Rate_B.Value, _
                            .Range("I:I"), Me.MealPlan_CB.Value) > 0 Then

        MsgBox "This is a duplicate"
        Exit Sub

    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

From a little googling I found the following earlier on Today:

1. The [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) accepts 127 range/criteria pairs. *(as already pointed out from @Tim Williams)*
2. The [WorksheetFunction.Countifs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countifs) accepts 30 args

As you aren't qualifying the `Countifs` method with `WorksheetFunction`, the VBE *intellisense* doesn't kick in. If you do you would see the following when starting to write your function:

[image: Screenshot of VBE intellisense showing 30 args]

This also confirmed my suspicion that the *Args* are in an pairs too, where for example *Arg1* is equivalent to *criteria_range1* from the COUNTIFS function, and *Arg2* is equivalent to *criteria1* from the COUNTIFS function.

---

This example uses a new blank workbook, a UserForm with 13 TextBox and 3 Checkbox, all with default names. Sheet1 is the 'Main' working sheet and Sheet2 is the helper sheet to evaluate our COUNTIFS data.

To use the `Countifs` method you may need to assign a part of an exising worksheet OR a new helper worksheet range to accept the values first, and evaluate the worksheet COUNTIFS function on the data, then if that function returns > 1 clear the helper range and exit sub, else clear the range and then do the rest of the thing:

On `Sheet2`, the following function was written in Cell `B1`:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A1,Sheet1!B:B,A2,Sheet1!C:C,A3,Sheet1!D:D,A4,Sheet1!E:E,A5,Sheet1!F:F,A6,Sheet1!G:G,A7,Sheet1!H:H,A8,Sheet1!I:I,A9,Sheet1!J:J,A10,Sheet1!K:K,A11,Sheet1!L:L,A12,Sheet1!M:M,A13,Sheet1!N:N,A14,Sheet1!O:O,A15,Sheet1!P:P,A16)
```

Now we temporarily place our UserForm values to Sheet2 from A1 to A16.
(**Note:** *this is written in the UserForm code module.*)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim TempArray As Variant

With Me
    TempArray = Array(.TextBox1.Value, .TextBox2.Value, .TextBox3.Value, .TextBox4.Value, _
                        .TextBox5.Value, .TextBox6.Value, .TextBox7.Value, .TextBox8.Value, _
                        .TextBox9.Value, .TextBox10.Value, .TextBox11.Value, .TextBox12.Value, _
                        .TextBox13.Value, .CheckBox1.Value, .CheckBox2.Value, .CheckBox3.Value)
End With

Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(TempArray) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

End Sub
```

There are a few ways you could do this but I've chosen to store the UserForm values in an Array and then write that array to the worksheet. This method is explained well on Chip Pearsons website under [VBA - Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)
**Note:** *As the `Array` function creates a zero-based array, I've had to resize the destination range (on sheet2) to the upperbound of the array + 1.*

SO, now our worksheet function COUNTIFS can evaluate the inputs and return the relevant value of 0 or 1+.

[image: Filled out Userform and input sample data to sheet2]
**Note:** *This screenshot shows the output with **NO** data on Sheet1, hence the COUNTIFS evaluates to 0.*

Based on the following sample data on Sheet1, this evaluates the COUNTIFS function to 1 due to Row 6:

[image: Sample sheet1 data]

From there, evaluate in your code if `B1` on `Sheet2` is greater than 0 and then do whatever you need to, like;

```
If Sheet2.Range("B1").Value > 0 Then
    MsgBox "This is a duplicate"
    Sheet2.Range("A1:A16").ClearContents    'Clears the temp values from Sheet2.
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "There are no duplicates, put your code here to write the new entry to your sheet."
End if

Sheet2.Range("A1:A16").ClearContents        'Clears the temp values from Sheet2.
```

It's important to include `Sheet2.Range("A1:A16").ClearContents` before any point the code completes or exits, so include it other places like in any error handling you might have to ensure the temporarily stored userform values are removed from the sheet each time the code is run.

Comment: Thank you Samuel this worked for me. I appreciate the time you put into helping me.

Comment: @RYu No worries, if it's resolved your issue, [you should mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).